# Laravel 5.2, connection refused after updating to El Capitan

Tags: mysql, laravel, workbench

Recently I just updated to El Capitan, and now I'm having trouble connecting to my database through workbench and through the web app. I haven't touched my project in a week, and today when I opened it up to work on it, I get the error:

`PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

My .env file looks like this:

```html
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql-***-*.############.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=***_*
DB_USERNAME=***_***
DB_PASSWORD=*******
```

and my database.php file looks like:

```html
'mysql' => [
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => env('DB_HOST','mysql-***-*.############.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT','3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE','***_*'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME','***_***'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD','*******'),
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'strict' => false,
'engine' => null,
],
```

I navigate to project folder, run `php artisan serve` try to log in, and I get the error, I try to register a new account, and I get the same error.

I tried running `composer config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, and `composer update`.  Nothing seems to be working, any ideas what's happening would be great.

I try logging into MySQL Workbench with the same database connection host, username, and password, and it gives me this message 
[SQL problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzYnp.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with El Capitan, I also have this OS and it works just fine for me, however I had faced this problem but it was related to the DB server's firewall the 3306 port was blocked and after I re-enabled it everything worked just fine so better to check your DB server firewall I believe your problem is related to firewall security or network issue your configurations are totally correct

Comment: I've asked the group member who's hosting the DB, and he said he hasn't changed a thing, also my team members are able to log in/ register new accounts just fine.

Comment: If they are working live then yes they won't face any problems

Comment: Why don't you try to put the ip address instead of the host name ?

Comment: I don't know, it's probably because it's what AWS gave my group member, and thats what he gave to me. It's weird, because a week before I updated my OS i could connect fine.

Comment: I made this DB for you and made a table called it test with id = 1 and name = test try to connect to it to see if your problem from the OS or the Host, the host name is : 149.56.171.6 , db : your_test , Username : test , password : 0d~27Mhn

Comment: Yeah, I can connect. I'm going to ask for one of my other members who can connect for their connection strings and see if I can start my way from there. I think I may have mistyped something. I appreciate the help Nour!